# I accidentally transposed a shell command. Is there any way to recover my source code?

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, gcc

The command I used gcc -o foo.c foo, left me with foo....I know bone head move.
I know use version control. Any way to recover the .c file? Just starting out and appreciate any help. Using a new vm and the back up was not on.

Comment: Are you using source control, even just locally?

Comment: Do you still have `foo.c` open in your editor? If so, just save it again.  If not, unfortunately, you're hosed.

Comment: Use version control, commit frequently.

Comment: I sadly was not using source control, thats changing now. zwol- I had it open in my editor (atom) but it wasn't there when I went back. I guess this is a great lesson in the values of git.

Comment: You can try `strings /dev/sda | grep -FC 500 'somethingUniqueInYourCode()' | tee ~/log` to look through the entire disk and see if maybe there's a trace of it somewhere in unallocated data

Comment: Some editors keep the last version of your file with a name like file~ or file.bak.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to recover foo.c through "normal" methods.

If you had another program that had opened the file, like an editor or debugger, you could try to recover the source code from there. Some editors like to automatically reload when the data on disk changes, though, so it's not a certainty.

Also, with a relatively high risk of failure, you may try to find the file using forensic tools designed to extract data from formatted or corrupted hard drives. [Foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) is one such program. The likelihood of success depends on what kind of filesystem the file was saved on and how much you've used it -- most filesystems will freely overwrite a file immediately after it was deleted. Some people say that if you accidentally delete an important file, you should immediately power off the machine (without letting it go through shutdown) to decrease the probability of that happening. Of course, then you need to boot from a USB stick or something to run forensics on the hard drive.

(My assumption is that `gcc -o foo` does not actually overwrite `foo`, but creates a new file and deletes the old one; this is almost certainly true, but if gcc actually opens the old file and overwrites it, forensics will do nothing for you.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I had debugged it in gdb would I be able to recover anything useful or would that session still need to be active?

Comment: @trentcl gdb certainly knows how to print out the text of the program, but it doesn't rely on it being embedded in the executable. It is not. What is embedded is the filename and the line number; to print the line, gdb just looks at the original file. If you delete or edit the original file, you'll get misleading or non-existent printouts.

Comment: @rici Yep, I was just testing it and you are right. Shall correct.

Comment: @DSeverns I'm thinking now about why I had that impression, and I'm pretty sure I've edited files while gdb was running and noticed that the edits didn't show up. So it's likely that if gdb had opened the file before you deleted it and was still running, you would be able to use it in that way. That pretty much goes for any program that opens files and can display their contents, though.

Comment: I traced the behavior of `gcc`. When it calls `ld`, `ld` checks for the existence of the output file `stat()`, deletes it `unlink()`, and finally creates it `open()` with options `O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC`. However, the filesystem may re-use the freed space immediately.

Comment: @trentcl: I tried a few things with gdb, but I couldn't find any sequence of commands which resulted in gdb keeping the source file open, so edits immediately showed up (as soon as they were committed to permanent storage, of course; while the edits are just in the editor's edit buffer, they're not visible through the file system). However, if it did keep the file open, then it would probably not see changes, because the editor will write the changes to a new file with the same name. In that case, you could extract the contents of the deleted but open file through the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: @rici Thanks for fact-checking. It's most likely my memory that is to blame (unless gdb changed its behavior in this respect). Good thought about `/proc`, though; I forgot / didn't know that you could do that.

Comment: Seems like an oversight, though. If you're editing and debugging at the same time, you'd want gdb to display the code you're debugging, not the version you just saved